# Open a frame for emacs instance via terminal?

Tags: frames, term

Say I have emacs open on one screen and on another I'm working in terminal.

I see a file I want to open in emacs. Is there a quick way I could do something like `emacs myfile` and have a new frame, but same emacs instance pop up?

*Or maybe this is the default behaviour(?), since it's hard to distinguish between a new frame and a second instance of emacs.*

Comment: Yes, you would need to start emacs as a server or run `emacsclient` binary instead of `emacs` and do `server-start` in that. [Ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html)

Answer (score 3):

`emacs --daemon` starts an emacs server this needs to be done only once (for every computer start of course).

You can then connect to this server with the program `emacsclient`.
All files you open from command line with `emacsclient -c FILENAME` run with the server instance.

If you run `emacs FILENAME` you start a new emacs process.